# Opening or creating a file from a DirectX 11.2 app

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to open an .obj file which contains the vertices and faces of a sphere from Blender. The problem is i can't seem, for the life of me, open the file which contains the .obj data. I have tried using a normal C++ way to write to .txt file to check where would the appilcation create it, and maybe try to put the .obj file in that folder. The code i have used to write to the .txt file is as follows:

```
std::ofstream myfile("nestotamo.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile.close();
}
else DebugPrint("Unable to open file");
```

The code i posted doesn't work, the file doesnt even get created. From where should i try to load the .obj file, and why can't i even create a regular .txt file to find out the location where the app places them.

The code i used to try to load the data is as follows:

```
   std::wifstream fileIn(path.c_str());

        if (fileIn)
        {
            while (fileIn)
            {
                wchar_t line[64];
                fileIn.getline(line, 64);
                DebugPrint(line);
            }
        }
        else {
            DebugPrint("\t The file wasnt loaded...\n");
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do either of the `DebugPrint` statements get executed? Are you sure you're looking in the correct place? You might want use absolute path names in case the current directory isn't what you assume it is.

Comment: yes, the DebugPrint gets printed, the one from the else clause, says that the file loaded. Also, i have tried printing the .is_open(), and it always outputs false. And not only that, but the file doesnt even get created, i have checked. I am not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that i can't use regular c++ when working with files becuase DirectX has some additional constrictions on working with those. But, luckily i have found that the file needs to be in the following folder:

```
Solution_Name\x64\Debug(or Release)\Projekt_Name\AppX
```

The code i used is:

```
        std::wifstream fileIn(path.c_str());

        if (fileIn)
        {
            DebugPrint("The file loading begun: \n\n");

            while (fileIn)
            {
                wchar_t line[64];
                memset(line, '\0', 64);
                fileIn.getline(line, 64);

                DebugPrint(line);
                DebugPrint("\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            DebugPrint("\t The file wasnt loaded...\n");
        }
```

Comment: I tried this to write to file - but it doesn't work for me.