# ofstream.is_open() always false in DirectX12 application using VS 2015

Tags: c++, ofstream, directx-12

I've been trying for hours now, and I can't for the life of me get my **DirectX12** application to write a simple file...

A bit about my setup:

- Windows 10 updated.
- DirectX12 default "spinning cube" application. DirectX 12 App (Universal Windows)
- Visual Studio 2015

I am doing this:

```
ofstream outFile;
// I have even tried with \\ slashes...
outFile.open("c://Users//pookie//Documents//WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt");
if (outFile.is_open())
{
    outFile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    outFile.close();
}
```

What I have tried (almost everything under the sun and the kitchen sink):

- I've also tried using `fstream`, `wfstream` as well as doing `!outfile.fail()`
- I've checked **every** directory in my project, and even ventured out into the Microsoft DirectX SDK.
- I've tried relative paths: `outFile.open("WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt");`
- I've tried setting an absolute path.
- I've tried adding permissions to the folder by allowing "everyone" and giving full access - just for sanity.
- I've also tried getting the current working directory, which is `C:\Users\pookie\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\demoDX12\x64\Debug\demoDX12\AppX` and setting it to `c:\`
- I have created the file manually, in every folder of my project...
- I've tried in both Debug and Release configs, as well as x86 and x64 and all possible combinations thereof
- I've tried `\\` as well as `//` in my file path
- I've tried replacing spaces in path with %20
- I have also tried running Visual Studio in admin mode.

The problem occurs here: `if (outFile.is_open())`. For some reason, it always returns false.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
To rest my mind, I tried an empty console application with the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        wfstream  outFile;
        outFile.open("C:\\Users\\pookie\\Documents\\WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt");
        if (outFile.is_open())
        {
            outFile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
            outFile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "sdsadsdsd";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is the same: `is_open() == false`. I'm at a loss here guys.

**Update 2:**

As requested, I am updating this question to show the exact project I am working with. I am working with the default DirectX12 application - the spinning cube. I [followed this tutorial](https://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/quickstart-directx-12-programming/)

Within my project, there is a method called `void DX::DeviceResources::Present()` and it is within this method that I am trying to write to file (although I have tried this in numerous other places within this project, too.

Here it is:

```
// Present the contents of the swap chain to the screen.
void DX::DeviceResources::Present()
{
    // The first argument instructs DXGI to block until VSync, putting the application
    // to sleep until the next VSync. This ensures we don't waste any cycles rendering
    // frames that will never be displayed to the screen.
    HRESULT hr = m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);

    try
    {
        wfstream  outFile;
        std::string 
         //This has been done numerous ways, but ultimately, I believe that 
         //ios_base::out is required if the file does not yet exist.
        name("c:\\Users\\pookie\\Documents\\WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt");
        outFile.open(name.c_str(), ios_base::out);
        if (outFile.is_open())
        {
            outFile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
            outFile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "sdsadsdsd";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what();
    }


    // If the device was removed either by a disconnection or a driver upgrade, we 
    // must recreate all device resources.
    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
    {
        m_deviceRemoved = true;
    }
    else
    {
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);

        MoveToNextFrame();
    }
}
```

**Update 3**

So, a blank project with file output works fine, if I use

```
name("c:\\Users\\pookie\\Documents\\WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt");
outFile.open(name.c_str(), ios_base::out);
```

Note the `ios_base::out`

This is fine. However, this does still not work in the default DirectX12 application.

This is definitely an DirectX related issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571859/opening-or-creating-a-file-from-a-directx-11-2-app). I have tried doing as the solution in that post suggested, but I can still not get it to work.

I can also confirm that a brand new DirectX12 project has the same issue. Try it.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to ebyrob, I have got this working. It turns out that these new Windows Apps can only write to certain folders... More specifically, this:

```
auto platformPath = ApplicationData::Current->RoamingFolder->Path;
```

Unfortunately, the path is not a standard string... so it must be converted first:

```
auto platformPath = ApplicationData::Current->RoamingFolder->Path;
std::wstring platformPathW(platformPath->Begin());
std::string convertedPlatformPath(platformPathW.begin(), platformPathW.end());
```

Then just add the file name:

```
std::string path = convertedPlatformPath + "\\WHERETHFISMYFILE.txt";
```

and finally:

```
try
{
    wofstream  outFile;
    char buff[256]; 
    outFile.open(path.c_str(), ios_base::out);
    if (outFile.is_open())
    {
        outFile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        outFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file " << name << ": " << strerror_s(buff,0) << endl;
    }
}
catch (const std::exception& ex)
{
    cout << ex.what();
}
```

Thank you ebyrob!!

Comment: What happens if you replace each `//` with `/`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Nothing. :(

Comment: did you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075930/c-fstream-is-open-function-always-returns-false

Comment: @pookie Well the `//` you show in your example is definitely wrong. And it has nowthing to do with direct-x.

Comment: Have you tried creating the file using Windows Explorer or similar tool?  If you can't create it that way, your program isn't going to work either.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Forgot to mention that yes, I did create the file. No luck.

Comment: @Pookie, have you attempted to simply write to a file within the working directory just to test if that is working? (E.g., trying something like `outFile.open("test_file.txt")`)

Comment: @SpencerDoak Yes, tried that too. Forgot to mention so. Will update post. Thanks.

Comment: Have you reversed the logic? As in `if (!outFile.is_open())`?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong. I've tried here and it worked fine with me. Only a question: have you opened the very same file before this piece of code?

Comment: Request the OP to replace '//' with '\\' in the code itself rather than explaining in the comments.

Comment: I am assuming you have checked to make sure the disk is not full.

Comment: @Paulo Nope, never opened the file previously. Did you try with the default DirectX12 project?

Comment: Can you try writing to the current directory in order to see if it's everything ok?

Comment: @pookie Have you tried checking if the file was even opened? Add an else statement to your condition; if that executes then the file was never opened to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, no. I've compiled with g++.

Comment: @Poriferous Just tried that. It hit the `else` ;(

Comment: @vk239 Nope, brand new project - didn't touch it other than this.

Comment: What that means is it's not a problem with your code, but more a problem with Windows. Try Linux!

Comment: @pookie Try adding this line `cout << strerror(errno) << endl;` after the `outFile.open()` line. Don't forget to add `#include <cerrno>` at the top.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with Windows and really, I shouldn't have to swap OS just to write to a text file ;)

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi the include gives me an error: `'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead.`

Comment: Most Windows installs do not have a `c:\users\user_name\documents`  They do have a `c:\users\user_name\my documents`  which is what the documents library points to be default,

Comment: @pookie `Try perror("Error : ");` instead.

Comment: @pookie Also, try `wfstream` (wide chars).

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi `no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion) ` - now I get that error.

Comment: @YamMarcovic `wfstream ` does not work, either. :(

Comment: @pookie see the edited comment.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Same error.

Comment: @pookie Try setting `outFile.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);` What happens then?

Comment: Are you sure you just wrote `perror("Error ");` after the `.open()` line? If yes, then could you tell me the exact compile error being generated from it?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi: Since `perror` is a POSIX function I don't think we should be entirely surprised that it fails to compile on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you able to write to the file from the command line?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess you're right. Windows really sucks!

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi: That's a bit like saying cars really suck because they don't have solar panels to let them fly through space and take photos of planets, but okay

Comment: @YamMarcovic When I do that, I get the exception: `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF89546037B (ucrtbased.dll) in UE4ClientDX12.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.`

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi I added `perror("Error ");` after `.open` and it now builds and runs, without exception but with the same result: `is_open() == false`

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit That's kind of overestimating perror. OP: surround with try/catch and print exception message, please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nice profile pic. Sorry, off-topic but couldn't help myself.

Comment: This could very well be a bug in the compiler itself.

Comment: @YamMarcovic I have wrapped my code in a try catch, but no exception is caught.

Comment: Just to be sure, the call to exceptions comes before the one to open, right?

Comment: @YamMarcovic Updated my post with try/catch and also in a blank console application.

Comment: You're not calling the exceptions function as I suggested

Comment: did you try opening a cmd window and typing cd "c:/users....." just to make sure the directory is there?

Comment: Maybe I missed it in the long thread of comments, but are you sure you're running the same program your editing? Check by adding `std::cin.get()` or something that requires your input.

Comment: If you create the file `WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt` ahead of time your code pretty much works as written.  If you instead want to create the file, it will work if you specify `ios_base::out` in `.open()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you please stop removing my `DirectX12` tag? I have it there for a reason. Thanks.

Comment: @pookie Well, I can't see the reason or relation. But if you insist to keep it I'll let you.

Comment: Why are you passing  ios_base::out to your string constructor and not to your ofstream constructor?

Comment: @jcoder Sorry, that was a type - not a copy and paste. Will update.

Comment: [File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

See this answer:

[std::fstream doesn't create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file)

You need to specify the correct options to `wfstream::open()` in order to create a new file.  `::in` without `::trunc` will require an existing file.

Example:

```
outFile.open("C:\\Users\\pookie\\Documents\\WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt", ios_base::out);
```

In this case, it seems there is another issue.  The application is part of Windows 10 app store, so it can only access files in a few locations.

Please see this thread: [Can't create file using fstream in windows store app 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815285/cant-create-file-using-fstream-in-windows-store-app-8-1)

For how to open a file in local or roaming user profile directories which the app actually *does* get access to.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, either. I tried the blank console application and it works there, but not with the default DirectX12 application, which is what I suspect is causing a conflict. However, someone keeps removing my DX12 tag...

Comment: your standalone app has the same issue but no dx12

Comment: @pookie I'll have to see what I can do later since I'm running on Windows 7 at the moment.  Please update your question with short and exact current source from your DX12 application.  (also use Oleg's `strerror(errno)` idea)

Comment: @pookie I'm thinking this might be an app store issue in which case this may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815285/cant-create-file-using-fstream-in-windows-store-app-8-1

Comment: @ebyrob Brilliant!! It works! Thank you so much! Update your answer and I will mark as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The root problem here is that the poster is writing a UWP, not a Win32 desktop app, which means the application does not have read or write access to arbitrary parts of the file system, specifically `C:\\Users\\pookie\\Documents\\WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt`.

> The use of DirectX 12 or not has no bearing on the problem.

The only parts of the file system that a UWP can directly access are:

- read-only access to the installed packaged directory. `Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation`
- read-write access to an isolated temporary file directory. `Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder`
- read-write access to an isolated per-user/per-application file directory either local or roaming. `Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder` or `RoamingFolder`;

To get access to a user documents folder in a UWP requires using Windows Runtime file pickers in `Windows.Storage.Pickers` or via `StorageFile` functionality with an appropriate declared capability. For such protected files, you also can't use C++ iostream operations directly as they might not even be a file on the local file system. You could use Windows Runtime APIs to copy the file to one of the locations above, and then use traditional C/C++ functions on the copy there.

Here is an example of using C/C++ functions to read a user file located in a protected area like user documents in UWP:

```
#include <ppltasks.h>
using namespace concurrency;

using Windows::Storage;
using Windows::Storage::Pickers;

create_task(openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([](StorageFile^ file)
{
    if (file)
    {
        auto tempFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder;
        create_task(file->CopyAsync(tempFolder, file->Name, NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName)).then([](StorageFile^ tempFile)
        {
            if (tempFile)
            {
                ifstream inFile(tempFile->Path->Data())
                ...
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is an example of using C/C++ functions to write a user file located in a protected area like user documents in UWP:

```
#include <ppltasks.h>
using namespace concurrency;

using Windows::Storage;
using Windows::Storage::Pickers;

auto folder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder;

WCHAR fname[ _MAX_PATH ];
wcscpy_s( fname, folder->Path->Data() );
wcscat_s( fname, L"\\MYFILE.txt" );

ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(fname, ios_base::out);

...

outFile.close();

create_task(savePicker->PickSaveFileAsync()).then([](StorageFile^ file)
{
    if ( file )
    {
        auto folder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder;
        auto task = create_task( folder->GetFileAsync("MYFILE.txt") );
        task.then([file](StorageFile^ tempFile) ->IAsyncAction^
        {
            return tempFile->MoveAndReplaceAsync( file );
        });
    }
});
```

See [File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) and [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx)

> Note that this model should be familiar to anyone who followed the Windows Vista era [User Account Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx) guidelines where your install directory should be read-only (i.e. under `C:\Program Files`), and you were supposed to use `SHGetFolderPath` with `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` / `CSIDL_APPDATA` for application data, and use `GetTempPath` for temporary directories you have read/write access to. With UWP, the rest of the file system is explicitly protected which for UAC it was not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is going wrong, but I hope this code will help you to diagnose the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream outFile;
    std::string name("c://Users//pookie//Documents//WHERETHEFISMYFILE.txt");
    outFile.open(name.c_str());
    if(outFile.is_open()) {
        outFile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        outFile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Cannot open file " << name << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
}
```

This code has been tested on MSVC++ [here](http://rextester.com/AXYS16631).

Comment: Thanks, I tried with strerror and the result is `no error`.

Comment: @pookie you may also want to try `strerror_s()` which is thread-safe.

Comment: @ebyrob I've tried that too :) it is definitely something to do with direct X. Apparently you must write to the app X folder, but that did not work for me either.